# WARNING in Circular dependency detected

Tags: angular

I have a typescript file that exports all the components I'm using. Just to get cleaner imports. Such as:

```
import{ Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 } from index/components
```

When using this method I get a warning when building when I import a child component into another component (since the component I'm importing into is exported in the same file I would believe).

Is this something I can ignore or will this result in a problem and should be done in another way?

components.ts example

```
export { EingreidslaSamningurComponent } from './../shared/components/usercontrols/samningar/eingreidsla-samningur/eingreidsla-samningur.component';
export { NyrlaunagreidandiComponent } from './../shared/components/usercontrols/samningar/nyrlaunagreidandi/nyrlaunagreidandi.component';
export { BankaupplysingarComponent } from "./../shared/components/usercontrols/bankaupplysingar/bankaupplysingar.component";
export { SamskiptaleidirComponent } from './../shared/components/usercontrols//samskiptaleidir/samskiptaleidir.component';
export { BreytaprosentuComponent } from './../shared/components/usercontrols/samningar/vidbot/breytaprosentu/breytaprosentu.component';
```

Component example:

```
import { SkilabodComponent, BankaupplysingarComponent } from '@index/components';
```

This gives me a warning:

**WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\index\components.ts -> src\app\shared\components\usercontrols\utgreidslur\utgreidslaskylda\utgreidslaskylda.component.ts -> src\app\index\components.ts**

Comment: I'd say warnings are not errors, but warnings aren't good either ... Have you taken a look at how (for instance) Angular Material does it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this warning, you will be in trouble in future and cannot easily say which component has errors.

If you import like parent -> child1 -> child2;

child2 may import child 1 if you do not divide them into small pieces of your structure.

better way :  export your child like components, services i mean the very small parts that will be used as reusable components not like pages. And then only import these on any other parent components. you can think like them as recursive backtracking.